# audio: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, audio, decoding

I am trying to decode an mp3 to a raw file.  I am trying to use madplay to accomplish this. I am running Debian Etch kernel 2.6.26-2-amd64.  I installed madplay using apt-get install madplay.

I am trying to output to raw format like this:

madplay -b 16 -R 44100 -S -o raw: /home/moh/music/Loungin.mp3

I am getting this output:

MPEG Audio Decoder 0.15.2 (beta) - Copyright (C) 2000-2004 Robert Leslie et al.

audio: No such file or directory

Any ideas?  I have tried running this as the "moh" user and also root and I'm getting the same error, so I don't think it is a permissions issue.

**** even doing just
madplay -o raw: Loungin.mp3
gives the same error

Comment: just to add...  ls /home/moh/music/ reads 
Loungin.mp3... so the file does exist =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a file name after the raw:, i.e.

```
madplay -o raw:file.out Loungin.mp3
```